# Windows Explorer Double-click opens new window (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When double-clicking on a folder in Windows Explorer list window it opens a new window. Tools->Folder Options->Open each folder in same window is selected.

How can I find which plugin or application is messing with this behavior? And fix it.

Comment: Still looking to solve this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a little old but I resolved this by changing the mentioned setting to "Open each folder in it's own window" and clicked Apply and then I set it back to "Open each folder in the same window" and clicked Apply again.

**Organize->Folder and search options->Open each folder in it's own window**

*Apply*

**Organize->Folder and search options->Open each folder in the same window**

*Apply*

Comment: Still applies to Windows 10 in 2020!

Comment: You saved my life on Windows 10 2023

Answer (score 1):

Check **Tools > Folder Options**

On the General tab (I think it's still there in Windows 7*), there's an option called "Browse Folders". Make sure the "Open each folder in the same window" option is selected.

* I can't double check at the moment as I don't have access to a Windows 7 machine at the weekend.

Comment: "Tools->Folder Options->Open each folder in same window is selected."?

Comment: @jswanson - oops. Thanks for the heads up. Brain going faster than fingers as usual.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old but I had this problem combined with single-click opens instead of double-click. It was caused by a GPO:
"Turn on Classic Shell" under "User Config/Admin Templates/Windows Components/Windows Explorer"
Setting it to "disable" worked for me.

In a .reg file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"ClassicShell"=dword:00000000
```

...You have to reboot your PC (or kill explorer.exe from Taskmanager and start task "explorer.exe")